# How does the indexing and retrieving performance degrade with increase in data size in elastisearch Service?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, model-associations

I would like to know how the performance of the ElasticSearch service decreases/degrades with in size of the data increasing. Are there any metrics which indicates this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on

- number of nodes in you cluster (more power and ram, but more time on communication between nodes)
- document structure (complex structure longer to process)
- indexing settings and mappings
- volume of indexing/search queries (big volume of indexing query could slowdown search or oposite)
- hdd speed for databases not fit in memory
- type of search queries (simple CRUD queries, document search, aggregation and analytics)

I would suggest you to start with [ElasticHQ](http://www.elastichq.org/) and [list of diagnostic metrics](http://www.elastichq.org/feature_list.html)

[image]

and [Marvel](https://www.elastic.co/products/marvel) from Elasticsearch

It will give you an idea of potential bottlenecks

Fill free to ask more specific questions when you have them

**ElasticSearch Usage Statistics**
from elasticsearch hq plugin

http://www.elastichq.org/elasticsearchstats.php

Comment: I wanted to know if there are some specific numbers which indicate the time taken to read as the indexed data increases. For eg: In a 10 node cluster with 5 TB of data what would be the read time (taking all ideal conditions) and what would be the read when the data is increased to 10 TB with the same conditions. 
So wanted to know if there is a table like is?

Comment: You can check http://www.elastichq.org/elasticsearchstats.php they collect anonymous statistics, on this table you can see extreme and average cases. Working with elasticsearch I could say it depends on specific structure of documents and type of request more than on volume of data. I usually check limitations for one node and than scale it to whole cluster horizontally.